# React and automation script

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, web-applications

I have a React-based web app that I need to include and run an Java automation script in the background to collect data.  Since I'm newbie to React, some questions:

1. Does React accept Java automation script OR does the script needs to be converted to JavaScript first?
2. How do I include and run the automation script in React?  I didn't find much info on that.

Thanks.

Comment: What is a Java automation script? The browser does not interpret Java, so if you want to run code on the client you'll need to transpile or rewrite in JS.

Comment: Automation script written in Java, which don't want to rewrite in JS.  If I have the automation script in JS, how do I include and run it in React?  A code sample would be a great help.

Comment: Right, I figured a Java automation script is an automation script written in Java .... but what does it do exactly? Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish here? Also, React is just a library written in Javascript, so there isn't any special way of "including" or "running" code from within it. You could include it using a script tag, or if you're using Webpack/browserify you could use `require` or `import` module syntax to include the dependency.

Comment: Thanks. Once Submit button is pressed in UI, automation script executes commands to gather system-related info and save into a JSON file or link to DynomoDB.  How is this accomplished in JS?  Sample codes if possible.